# Adding time on bid placing when time less than 3 minute

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I used a hook on my product page and added a function to add 10 minutes (600 seconds) of bidding time when any bid has been placed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_auctions_outbid', 'woocommerce_simple_auctions_extend_time', 50 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_auctions_proxy_outbid', 'woocommerce_simple_auctions_extend_time', 50 );
 
function woocommerce_simple_auctions_extend_time($data){
    $product = get_product( $data['product_id'] );
    if ('auction' === $product->get_type() ){
        $date1 = new DateTime($product->get_auction_dates_to());
        $date1->add(new DateInterval('PT600S'));
        update_post_meta( $data['product_id'], '_auction_dates_to', $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
    }
}
```

but when customer bid, it will increase 10 min by anytime(I don't want the bid time increase to a huge number), so I probably need to set a limit that this code only effect when bid time less than 3 minutes.

**Edit:**

I am changing the code to the limit time with an if validation, but it still add the time when the countdown more than 3 minute:

```
function woocommerce_simple_auctions_extend_time($data){
    $product = get_product( $data['product_id'] );
    if ('auction' === $product->get_type() ){
        //check if time shorter than 3 min
        $date1 = new DateTime($product->get_auction_dates_to());
        $current_dt = new DateTime('NOW');
        $interval= date_diff($current_dt, $date1);
        $remaining_seconds = $interval->format("%s");
        
        if($remaining_seconds < 180) {
        // add time
        $date1->add(new DateInterval('PT600S'));
        update_post_meta( $data['product_id'], '_auction_dates_to', $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used current_time(timestamp) to capture the current time, and used
strtotime('+5 minutes', $time) to compare with the auction deadline.

Here is the code that I can run successfully:

```
$time = current_time('timestamp' );
         $timeplus5 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', $time));
 
         if ($timeplus5> $auctionendformat) {
             $auctionend->add(new DateInterval('PT600S'));
             update_post_meta( $data['product_id'],'_auction_dates_to', $auctionend->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the product end time `$date1` and run a difference against another datetime object for the current time and check if the difference is less than 3 minutes.

If it's less than 3 minutes then add your 10 minutes to the end time for the product.

```
$current_dt = new DateTime('NOW');
$interval= date_diff($current_dt, $date1);
$remaining_seconds = $interval->format("%s");

if($remaining_seconds < 300) {
  // add time
}
```

[PHP DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: I added a time difference judgment to the code, but I still seem to ignore the judgment and add a countdown of 10 minutes at any time period.